# Не получается создать папку sampledata в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В документации написано: Чтобы создать папку, щелкните правой кнопкой мыши папку app в окне Project и выберите New > Sample Data Directory. Я делаю это, но, по какой-то причине, ничего не происходит
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне с этим делать

Comment: после создания обновите дерево, либо в той же директории создайте папку с другим названием

Comment: @danilshik, как обновить дерево? (sorry за тупой вопрос, но я этого ещё не делал)

Comment: @danilshik, папку с другим названием создал, но sampledata не появилась

Comment: просто так тут папки не создают, за исключением assets

Answer (score 0):

есть такая проблема у студии. С чем связано не знаю.
Решается созданием папки вручную в
`projectRoot/app/sampledata`
она и в дереве студии отобразится